# Get Time like "2022-05-15T06:48:10.189Z"

Tags: python

I am attempting to get the current time formatted into the string similar to `2022-05-15T06:48:10.189Z`,

How would I be able to do that with python, is it `datetime` or `time`?

Comment: What have you tried till now? Did you do some research on Google or Stackoverflow?

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish I am still researching, but I don't know what to add because i'm confused on what the name of the format of that is.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `datetime` at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html ... the method you want is `isoformat()`. Your first port of call for questions like this requires no searching because Python documentation is always good and mostly exemplary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Zulu Time Zone in [military time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones), the letter Z indicates UTC.

You can use `utcnow()` and `isoformat()`, for example:

```py
print(f'{datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3]}Z')
```